# I am having trouble with the .compareTo function

Tags: java

This is probably a very easy fix, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I get the error "cannot resolve method .compareTo(double)"

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    Double angle = getUserDouble("Enter an angle in degrees:");
    Double userHeightInput = getUserDouble("Enter the height in meters:");

    final double G = 9.81; 
    final double DT = 0.01; 
    double theta = 45;
    double speed = 100.0; 
    double xPos = 0.0;
    double yPos = userHeightInput;
    double vX = speed *Math.cos(2.*Math.PI*theta/360);
    double vY = speed *Math.sin(2.*Math.PI*theta/360);
    double aY = -1.0;
    double aX = 0.0;
    double time = 0.0;

   FileWriter out = new FileWriter("output.csv");

   while (yPos.compareTo(0.0) > 0.0)
    {
        xPos = xPos + vX * DT;
        yPos = yPos + vY * DT;
        vX   = vY + aX * DT;
        vY   = vY + aY * DT;
    }
    String line = time + "," + xPos + "," + yPos + ","+ vX + "," +vY;
    out.write(line);
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: What is `yPos`? Could you post a [mre]?

Comment: It looks like `yPos` is a `double` and not a `Double` (or a `float`, same difference). That's why you can't call methods on it. Just compare it liek this: `yPos > 0`.

Comment: If a variable is primitive (`int`, `double`, `boolean`, etc.), you can't call methods on it. You can compare it with `>=`, `<=`, `<` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this error is happening because .compareTo() must be called on objects, but double is a primitive type. Try making a simple comparison using operators like >, <, ==. Example:

```
while (yPos > 0.0)
```

Another option would be parsing double to Double, to make it work. However, the option above seems to be the more obvious and recommendable one.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a method from a primitive. Use an instance of `Double` instead of `double`.

```
Double yPos = new Double(value);
```

I assume you might need to change your printout when doing this, in this case use `yPos.doubleValue()`